# How to upload a file using Reskit in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

How would I go about uploading an audio file using Restkit? I've looked around the documentation and can't seem to find anything about uploading files. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This article explains how: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/advanced-restkit-development_iphone-sdk/

Excerpt:

```
NSString* myFilePath = @"/some/path/to/picture.gif";
RKParams* params = [RKParams params];

// Set some simple values -- just like we would with NSDictionary
[params setValue:@"Blake" forParam:@"name"];
[params setValue:@"blake@restkit.org" forParam:@"email"];

// Create an Attachment
RKParamsAttachment* attachment = [params setFile:myFilePath forParam:@"image1"];
attachment.MIMEType = @"image/gif";
attachment.fileName = @"picture.gif";

// Attach an Image from the App Bundle
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"another_image.png"];
NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[params setData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/png" forParam:@"image2"];

// Let's examine the RKRequestSerializable info...
NSLog(@"RKParams HTTPHeaderValueForContentType = %@", [params HTTPHeaderValueForContentType]);
NSLog(@"RKParams HTTPHeaderValueForContentLength = %d", [params HTTPHeaderValueForContentLength]);

// Send a Request!
[[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/uploadImages" params:params delegate:self];
```

Enjoy!

Comment: That's the one, how did I not find that page! Thanks

Comment: Hidden in plain sight ;-) No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

For Restkit 0.20, the MIME types are automatically detected when creating the attachement. So you do not need to call

```
attachment.MIMEType
```

And when building the params:

```
[params setData:imageData MIMEType:attachment.MIMEType forParam:@"image2"];
```

see this [link](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/tree/development#post-an-object-with-a-file-attachment)